# Check values corresponding to the pd.idxmin() and filter with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry, I couldnt find any good title for it. Feel free to change it.

This is my sample dataframe

```
ID,Val1,Val2,Val3
1,10,9,11
2,14,15,16
3,17,18,1
1,22,25,3
```

I want to check row by row value of each columns except ID and if there is minimum number which is greater than 4, then I would like to drop those columns.
Here in this case, ID 1(top) and 2 has the minimum number greater than 4. So I want to drop both of those rows from the dataframe.

I cannot check using the column names because in my real dataframe, i would have 100s of columns and I dont even know their name.

To find the minimum value per each row, I am using `idxmin`.

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID').idxmin(axis=1).reset_index(name= 'New')
```

I have the output of this

```
ID   New
 1  Val2
 2  Val1
 3  Val3
 1  Val3
```

My question is that, is there a way that I can track the value corresponding to these new output so that I can apply simply `(df1['New] > some conditions)` and remove those rows based on the conditions.

for example, in this case the final output would be (after dropping those rows minimum number greater than 4)

```
ID New
 3  Val3
 1  Val3
```

Or is there any other easier way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `min` with first dataframe

```
df1.loc[df.iloc[:,1:].min(1)<4]
Out[270]: 
   ID   New
2   3  Val3
3   1  Val3
```