# problem with selecting data using pandas. iloc

Tags: python, pandas

This is sample dataframe

```
ID,IS,Val1,Val2,Val3
1,100,11,9,1
2,101,3,15,16
3,99,10,18,3
1,97,29,25,26
```

I am also using idxmin to calculate each rows  minimum value and when i find the minimum value, I want to check if that minimum value corresponding to that column is less than some number and if it is, then I want to include otherwise I want to remove it. 
This is what I am doing with the help of [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209133/check-values-corresponding-to-the-pd-idxmin-and-filter-with-some-conditions).

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID').iloc[:,1:].idxmin(axis=1).reset_index(name= 'New')

df2 = df1.loc[34 > df.iloc[:, 1:].min(1)]
```

I got this result

```
ID   New
 1  Val3
 2  Val1
 3  Val3
 1  Val2
```

I also got the same result when I am using this code

`df2 = df1.loc[34 > df.iloc[:, 3:].min(1)]` # in this code, I am starting my column from Val2
but it still gives the same result (including Val1)

```
ID   New
 1  Val3
 2  Val1
 3  Val3
 1  Val2
```

Why I am getting same result even though I am selecting from third column? 
What exactly this line of code is doing here ?
    df1.loc[34 > df.iloc[:, 1:].min(1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `df2` is selecting from the columns headed `Val2` and `Val3` only, but as long as your code for `df1` still includes `Val1` then you will still see `Val1` in the output.

It may be easier to see what's going on if you use the column headers to index the data and add the new columns to the same data frame.

```
group1 = df[["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]] # find the min among these 3 cols
group2 = df[["Val2", "Val3"]]   # find the min among only these 2 cols
df["min1"] = group1.min(axis=1)
df["col1"] = group1.idxmin(axis=1)
df["min2"] = group2.min(axis=1)
df["col2"] = group2.idxmin(axis=1)

filtered1 = df.loc[12 > df.min1]  # Val3, Val1, Val3 contain the minimum values
filtered2 = df.loc[12 > df.min2]  # Val3, Val3 contain the minimum values
```

Answer (score 2):

Both your Boolean conditions return all true for each row , that is why you have same result

```
34 > df.iloc[:, 3:].min(1)
Out[202]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
34 > df.iloc[:, 1:].min(1)
Out[203]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

`iloc` is slice the dataframe by position

```
df.iloc[:, 1:]
Out[204]: 
    IS  Val1  Val2  Val3
0  100    11     9     1
1  101     3    15    16
2   99    10    18     3
3   97    29    25    26
```

Comment: But isnt the iloc selecting all rows but from third column if i use `df.iloc[:,3:]`

Comment: @Ben you should using `df.iloc[:,3]`

Comment: `df.iloc[:,3:]` would select all rows (`:`) and from column index 3 onwards (`3:`)

Comment: @rahlf23 , exactly I wanted to select all rows and from third column onward. But i got the value which is in second column too...thatswhy I was more curious like why it did that...

Comment: Keep in mind that Python indexes from 0, so the third column will actually be index 2